# How would you plot co-ordinates on a grid made from equilateral triangles?

Tags: geometry, triangles, coordinate-systems

The standard square grid has two axis: x and y, how would a grid made from tesselating equilateral triangles work? (An isometric grid) Triangles don't have 2 sets of parallel sides, like squares so as far as I can tell 3 axis are needed:

[image]

But then there is no easy way of interpreting it as each axis must have its respective grid lines coming of it from either a 30' angle or a 60' angle. And you have the problem where not all coordinate combinations can actually lie on the grid, eg. (x:1, y:2, z:3).

Is there some pre-existing method/standard of plotting "isometric coordinates" or is there no other way?

Comment: What do you mean by respecting some algebra?

Comment: The picture makes it clear. Two equilateral triangles make a parallelogram. You can use the parallelogram coordinates to assign coordinate pairs (x,y) to any vertex. The z will be determined by the (x,y) pair and so can be omitted from the coordinate system.

Comment: You may find interesting [this site](https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/)

Answer (score 2):

If you use just two of the axes on your diagram then you have an unambiguous set of coordinates for your system.

Comment: But then it will only a given set of coordinates, would direct you to a rhombus made form 2 triangles, as opposed to 1 triangle

Comment: Starting from a corner of a triangle, that triangle could have coordinates  (0,0),(0,1),(1,0). A rhombus would have vertices at (0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0).

Comment: @AnyTraingle The diagonals of rhombus will be given by (i+j) and (i-j). This is a 2-d plane so two axes are sufficient.

Comment: @AnyTraingle On a square grid you can associate any square with the coordinate of its bottom-left vertex, and this gives a 1-1 correspondence between squares and the integer coordinates. The triangular grid has twice as many triangles as vertices, so that is not possible. You could associate the upright triangles with the integer coordinates, and the reversed triangles with the half-integer coordinates (which are the centres of the rhombuses). Or do that but scaled by a factor 2, so that the triangles are associated with all the integer coordinates where x,y have the same parity.